# Image overflowing div advice

Tags: html, css

Im sure this is really easy but i have been looking at this issue for a little while and my brain has gone blank. I have a div that then has an image inside of it. The image seems to just overflow the div border and its driving me mad. I have an image below to show you what is happening along with the css.

[image]

```css
#avatar {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#avatar img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="avatar">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/dkzoNCc.png"></div>
```

I have a border on the main div #avatar just so i can see the whole size of the div. All i want is for the image to scale to the size of the div. If i set the height to 100% it goes into the div just fine but when resizing it it starts to overflow the div. I want the image to resize on the width not height.

Am i missing something really simple here? I dont want to use overflow hidden on the image as that will just cut some of it off i believe.

Thanks everyone

Comment: how about `#avatar img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}`

Comment: Its because of your `#avatar img { height: auto; }` change it to `#avatar img { height: 100%; }`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try below css for `img`.

- use `height: 100%;` for maximum height
- `display: block;margin: auto;` for centering
- `max-width: 100%;` to fit large images

Please check the example with large and small images.

```css
#avatar {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#avatar img {
height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
display: block;
margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="avatar">
  <img src="http://www.baraodasfestas.com.br/Assets/Produtos/SuperZoom/0431_MICKEY_635703672330071491.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div id="avatar">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/d4/Mickey_Mouse.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: That seems to have done the job perfect! thanks very much for all the help. I knew it would end up being something simple. Seems it was just that 'max-width' that was missing :-)

Answer (score 9):

Just add:

```
#avatar img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
#avatar {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#avatar img {
  /*width: 100%;*/
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="avatar">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/dkzoNCc.png"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of your `height:auto` for the `<img>`

Just use :

```
#avatar img 
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

But this will stretch you image. So if you want full size image inside your container you need to stretch your container instead. Like

```
#avatar 
{
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#avatar img 
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```